# SQLite Python - Foreign Key Insert selection not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQLite database that I'm populating using the below function in Python. I want to use a SELECT statement in the insert statement in order to retrieve the fk user_id.

It works perfectly fine executing in the DB Browser, but when I try and run this function through Python it inserts the string literal and doesn't execute the SELECT query.

For example, when I pull the record in the DB Browser, it shows the user_id as "(SELECT user_id FROM User WHERE first_name = 'john' AND last_name = 'johnson' AND dob = '1980-10-10')"

Any advice on how to fix this? I want to be able to insert into the Reservation table using the user_id foreign key restraint.

UPDATE:
I was able to get it to work, somewhat, with the code below. I can only search with one Where clause, which isn't ideal because multiple people can have the same birthdate, but I think I'm getting somewhere.

```
cur.execute('SELECT user_id FROM User WHERE dob = ?', (dob, ))
user_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Reservation (flight_date, destination, seat_nums, user_id)
            VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )''', (flightdate, destination, seats, user_id,))
```

```
    def load_database(self, first_name, last_name, dob, email, destination, flightdate, seats):

        cur = super().get_cursor

        # tuple with one value has a comma after it. databases use tuples
        cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO User (first_name, last_name, dob, email)
            VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )''', (first_name, last_name, dob, email,))

        # this works in the DB Browser but not in this execute statement. Why not?
        # it inserts the whole string
        user_id_str = f"(SELECT user_id FROM User WHERE first_name = '{first_name}' AND last_name = '{last_name}' AND dob = '{dob}')"

        cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Reservation (flight_date, destination, seat_nums, user_id)
            VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )''', (flightdate, destination, seats, user_id_str,))

        super().get_connection.commit()
```

Comment: The point of bound parameters using the `?` operator is to insert them as is and prevent SQL injection attacks.  You can just call it with something like `cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Reservation (flight_date, destination, seat_nums, user_id) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, (SELECT user_id FROM User WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name =  AND dob = ?))''', (flightdate, destination, seats, first_name, last_name, dob))`

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working:

```
cur.execute('SELECT user_id FROM User WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ? AND dob = ?', (first_name, last_name, dob, ))
        user_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Reservation (flight_date, destination, seat_nums, user_id)
            VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )''', (flightdate, destination, seats, user_id,))
```